# Angular - Strapi Upload file during entry creation through formdata

Tags: angular, typescript, form-data, strapi

I followed the documentation from Strapi to upload file during entry creation, but the data from Angular is not sending properly to the back. I tested the back with Postman and it works perfectly, so I guess the `formData` object is not creating properly.

Here is my submit action:

```
async onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('files.resume', this.form.get('resume').value);
      formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(this.form.value));
      
      const res = await this.apiService.addResume(formData);
    }   
}
```

And the back is giving me:

```
error error: invalid input syntax for integer: "[object Object]"
```

If I console the `formData` entries, it looks like I want (exactly like when I insert data in Postman), so I don't know where the problem is.